# Which chapters do these exercises belong in?

Tags: probability

I don't need solutions, only chapters or area of math probability which these exercise belong in.

1. $60\%$ of all students eat in grocery stores. We choose group of students in random way. How many students must be in group so we can tell with a $90\%$ probability that the chosen group does not contain more than $20$ students who eat in grocery stores.
2. Determine the distribution of a random variable X whose characteristic function:
   $$h_{x}(t)=\frac{1}{7}\cos(4t)+\frac{1}{14}\cos(3t)+\frac{1}{4}\cos(2t)+\frac{1}{2}\cos(t)+\frac{1}{28}.$$
3. The X label has a distribution:
   \begin{pmatrix}
   -1 & 0 & 1\\ 
   \theta & 2\theta & 1-3\theta
   \end{pmatrix}
   Based on the sample $(1,1,-1,0,1,1,-1,0)$ by the method of maximum credibility, find the estimate of the unknown parameter $\theta$.

Comment: No $\space \space$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) is about the binomial distribution.

(2) is about characteristic functions.

(3) appears to be about "maximum credibility" which may be an actuarial term (unless credibility is just a synonym for likelihood here).